# how do i create a text on path?

Tags: text, background

i really want to know how to create texts in a background using corel draw 4, for example on some currencies and certificates, you may have, "Bank of Ghana, Bank of Ghana", written plenty in a wavy style with small sized fonts in the background or if its a school, you have the name of the school written plenty but small small font size in the background. Any help please??

Comment: is this relevant to SO? I've never really seen support for drawing programs

Answer (score 0):

How to Create Text on Path as per Example

1. Draw a path
2. Type Text

Example
[image]

3. Select Both Path and ext
4. Click Text from Menu and Click Fit Text to Path

Example
[image]

Finish
[image]
If you find my answer helpful please mark it, So others can take the benefits of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add any text along the path of an open object like line or a closed object like squre or circle.

1. Draw any path (cirlce, squre, lines)
2. Type Text

[Type Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNpek.jpg)

3. With Pick tool , select a path.

[Select Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg0FW.jpg)

4. Click Text  Fit text to path.

[Text-> Fit to Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bqRF.jpg)

5. You can also edit fit text to a path by clicking these icons.

[Edit Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BBwk.jpg)